# Convert Joda-Time DateTime - ISO 8601 format date to another date format

Tags: java, jodatime

Inside my Java app I am using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to convert the app user entered date from MM/dd/yyyy to ISO 8601 format in order to save it in DB.

Can someone please tell me how I can convert the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date back to MM/dd/yyyy format using Joda-Time?

My code convert user date to ISO 8601 date format:

```
String date1 = "05/05/2013";
DateTimeFormatter parser1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateTime dateTimeObj1 = DateTime.parse(date1,parser1);
DateTimeFormatter isoDateFormat = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
String isoDateStr = isoDateFormat.print(dateTimeObj1);
System.out.println(isoDateStr);
```

Comment: Do you want to do this at a later stage where you only have the date in an ISO format? You can just parse the value into a `DateTime` object and format it in your `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Use Same Formatter

You **use the same DateTimeFormatter** object to parse as to `print` (render a string) in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

## Time Zone

Note that your code neglected to address a [time zone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). In that case you get the JVM's default time zone. Not a good practice.

A DateTime represents both a date and a time. When parsing a string for only the date portion, the time portion is automatically set to first moment of the day. That first moment varies by time zone. So applying a different time zone gives a different result, a different point along the timeline of the Universe, a different milliseconds-since-epoch.

Note the call to [`withZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) when defining the formatter.

## Strings

Keep in mind that DateTime objects are *not* Strings. You can generate a string representation of the date-time information contained inside a DateTime by either:

- Call the `toString` method on the DateTime instance.
  Every DateTime has a built-in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) [formatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html), used automatically by the "toString" method.
- Instantiate your own `DateTimeFormatter` instance.

Both of these string-generation techniques are seen in the example code below.

## Example Code

```java
// Usually better to specify a time zone than rely on default.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Hong_Kong" );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy" ).withZone( timeZone );

// Parse string into a DateTime. Define the format.
String input = "05/05/2013";
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( input ); // Defaults to first moment of the day.

// Render date-time as an ISO 8601 string. The "toString" method on DateTime defaults to a built-in ISO 8601 formatter.
// A DateTime object is not itself a string. But a DateTime can generate a string by calling its "toString" method.
String iso8601String = dateTime.toString();

// Parse string into a DateTime. Passing to constructor conveniently uses the built-in ISO 8601 parser built into DateTime class.
DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime( iso8601String, timeZone );

// Render date-time as a string in a particular format.
String output = formatter.print( dateTime2 );
```

Rather than hard-code a specific format, you can soft-code a localized format.

```
String outputUS = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "S-" ).withLocale( Locale.US ).print( dateTime2 );
String outputQuébécois = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "F-" ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).print( dateTime2 );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime ); // Implicit call to "toString" method in DateTime class generates a new string using a built-in formatter for ISO 8601 format.
System.out.println( "iso8601String: " + iso8601String );
System.out.println( "dateTime2: " + dateTime2 ); // Another implicit call to "toString" method on DateTime class. Generates a new string in ISO format.
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2013-05-05T00:00:00.000+08:00
iso8601String: 2013-05-05T00:00:00.000+08:00
dateTime2: 2013-05-05T00:00:00.000+08:00
output: 05/05/2013
```

## String Is Not a Date-Time

Do not think of date-time objects as strings.

A `DateTime` has no format. That class can parse a String in ISO 8601 format to instantiate a date-time object. Likewise a `DateTimeFormatter` can parse a String to instantiate a date-time object.

Going the opposite direction, a `DateTime` has a `toString` implementation that generates a String representation of the date-time object’s value. Likewise a `DateTimeFormatter` can generate a String representation of the date-time  object’s value.

In all these cases the String representation is entirely different and separate from the date-time object.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I am a bit confused here, in the DateTime dateTime step we already have the date in ISO8601 Format as shown from the println, so why we did the String iso8601String step to retrieve the date in ISO8601 format again?

Comment: @MChan Because you asked for it. I'm showing a full cycle: string (date only) → DateTime instance → string (ISO) → DateTime instance → string (date only). In the DateTime dateTime line, we do **not** have an ISO string. An ISO string is *generated* in the first System.out.println line where the `toString` method on the `dateTime` object is implicitly called. A `DateTime` instance is *not* a string, but it can *produce* an ISO string by calling its `toString` method, which in turn calls a built-in formatter. Read the doc. If you want any other kind of string, define your own formatter instance.