# Failed to concisely convert String with milliseconds to Date type in Java

Tags: java, datetime, date-conversion

Please find the following codes:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TestTimestamp {

    private final static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    private final static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");

    @Test
    public void test() throws ParseException {
        getTimestamp("20140512 16:13:09.493166 +0800", sdf);
        getTimestamp("20140515 15:04:42.690873 +0800", sdf);
        getTimestamp("20140515 15:04:45.159977 +0800", sdf);

        getTimestamp("20140512 16:13:09.493166 +0800", df);
        getTimestamp("20140515 15:04:42.690873 +0800", df);
        getTimestamp("20140515 15:04:45.159977 +0800", df);
    }

    private void getTimestamp(String time, SimpleDateFormat sdf) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println("Time to convert: " + time);
        String[] tmp = time.split("\\+");
        String str = tmp[0].trim();
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(sdf.parse(str));
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

The output with `sdf` is very strange and the output with `df` is correct:

```
//Wrong result with sdf
Time to convert: 20140512 16:13:09.493166 +0800
20140512 16:13:09.493166
Mon May 12 16:21:22 CST 2014

Time to convert: 20140515 15:04:42.690873 +0800
20140515 15:04:42.690873
Thu May 15 15:16:12 CST 2014

Time to convert: 20140515 15:04:45.159977 +0800
20140515 15:04:45.159977
Thu May 15 15:07:24 CST 2014


//Correct result with df
Time to convert: 20140512 16:13:09.493166 +0800
20140512 16:13:09.493166
Mon May 12 16:13:09 CST 2014

Time to convert: 20140515 15:04:42.690873 +0800
20140515 15:04:42.690873
Thu May 15 15:04:42 CST 2014

Time to convert: 20140515 15:04:45.159977 +0800
20140515 15:04:45.159977
Thu May 15 15:04:45 CST 2014
```

Could you please help me out?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you don't need the millisecond precision you could update your split to limit 3 digits beyond the decimal? `String[] tmp = time.split("\\d{3}\\s\\+");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Joda-Time DateTime - ISO 8601 format date to another date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505858/convert-joda-time-datetime-iso-8601-format-date-to-another-date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a millisecond would be SSS being a thousandth. The 159977 length would exceed this being a microsecond

try

`yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

Comment: Yeah, I think what it has done is duly converted your 6-digit numbers as milliseconds, which rolled over into seconds, mins, etc.  I don't see a format number for nanoseconds on the version of the SimpleDateFormat javadoc I'm looking at...

Comment: That's correct.  `SimpleDateFormat` only works with a `Date`, which has milliseconds only, no microseconds or nanoseconds.  You may have to write your own `DateFormat` implementation if you want to show or parse microseconds.

Comment: Correction: 6 digits is microsecond. A nanosecond is 9 digits, millisecond is 3.

Comment: @BasilBourque cheers, correction made, I always get confused whether I have a million or a billion in my bank

Answer (score 0):

Both a java.util.Date and Joda-Time have millisecond precision. So they can handle only three digits of a fraction. Either truncate the last three digits of the fraction, or use the new java.time package in Java 8 which can handle nanosecond precision (9 digits).